# ActionBarSherlock Missing libary.jar

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I was trying to add the actionbarsherlock libary moet I'm getting the following error:

```
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved            Unknown Java Problem
```

When I look into the tab 'Builth path' I see libary.jar is missing. But there isn´t a file called libary.jar?

I've already set the compiler to Java 1.6, but it's still not working. The target SDK of both projects is Android 4.0

I hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to switch to Java 1.7 and let Android fix my project properties. (I got a message). After that, it worked for me!